# what is the solution to the oracle database configuration Assistant installation echec

Tags: windows-10, database, oracle-database

I'm installing oracle 19c on windows 10.at the installation a n **echec** appears  **"Echec de l'élément Assistant Configuration de base de données Oracle."**
i don't know what means or how to solve it.
translate of the echec: **"the Oracle Database Configuration Wizard item failed"**

[the image shows the echec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JC8D.png)

Comment: echec in anglais, s'il vous plaît ?

Comment: "the Oracle Database Configuration Wizard item failed"

Comment: Are you installing it as Administrator?

Comment: yes i installed as admin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I found a solution. Before i tell you the solution,first, i have installed an other version of oracle before trying to install oracle 19c. second, uninstall it but not completed, that 's why that echec appears.

***. The solution *** is uninstall last version very well (for someone has installed oracle before and he want to change version):

**1. Shutdown all services of oracle .**
   **2. Remove all oracle environment variables** (*be careful to remove others variables*).
   **3. Remove oracles register from register** (*be careful here too  you have to remove just those contains oracle word *).
   **4. Remove all oracle files installed on windows.**
     **5. Reboot your system.**
Any an others questions related to what i wrote just comment here.
an other thanks to Dr Moishe for answer my question.